# Search for Text Surrounded by Double Quotes and Convert to HTML Entities

Tags: php, regex

I have a long text with many paragraphs. I need to search out all instances where text is surrounded by quotes, so "...", and replace it with &ldquo;...&rdquo;.

I'd also like to detect if a quote is missing a closing quote and not convert that obviously.

This is the best I can come up with right now:

```
$text = preg_replace('/(?<=\s)"(.+?)"(?=\s)/', '&ldquo;\1&rdquo;', $text);
```

But not sure if that will cover all cases. Any other suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any objective standard to choose if a double quote is an opening or closing quote except perhaps that there's no word character before an opening quote or after a closing quote in a "normal" text.

You can try to do that:

```
$text = preg_replace('/\B"([^"]*)"\B/u', '&ldquo;$1&rdquo;', $text);
if (strrpos($text, '"') !== false)
    $text = rtrim(str_replace('"', '&ldquo;', $text)) . '&rdquo;';
```